# Java EE Multiple SessionBeans with TimerService

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic12c

I have a Stateless Session Bean with a TimerService.
On timeout, it starts consuming a JMS queue. In the processing of the message it requires access to an external resource which may be temporary unavailable. The timeout method calls `MessageConsumer.receiveNoWait()` in a loop until:

- There are no more messages to process: it registers a new timer= now + 10minutes. And ends.
- an error occured during the processing: it rollbacks the message and registers a new timer: now + 30minutes. And ends.

This way I'm in control when to restart and I have no sleeping threads thanks to the TimerService callback.

I would like to have multiple occurances of this session bean to anticipate bottlenecks on the queue:

```
                    +-----<ejb>-------+
                    | timerService    |
                    |                 |              +---------------------+
                ----| onTimeout() {}  | -----------> | external dependency |
               /    |                 |         /    +---------------------+ 
              /     +-----------------+        /
             /                                /
+---------+ /                                /
|||queue|||K                                /
+---------+ \                              /
             \      +-----<ejb>-------+   /
              \     | timerService    |  /
               \    |                 | /
                ----| onTimeout() {}  | 
                    |                 |
                    +-----------------+
```

My session bean looks like this (simplified of course):

```
@Stateless
public class MyJob {
    
    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        registerNewTimer(1000L); // -> problem: timerService not accessible
        System.out.println("Initial Timer created");
    }

    private void registerNewTimer(long duration) {
        TimerConfig config = new TimerConfig();
        config.setPersistent(false);
        timerService.createSingleActionTimer(duration, config);
    }

    @Timeout
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void execute() {
        try {
            // instantiate JMS session and consumer
            while ((message = consumer.receiveNoWait()) != null) {
                // business logic with message
                message.acknowledge();
            }
            // queue empty, let's stop for now and register a new timer + 10min
            registerNewTimer(10*60*1000);
        } catch (ResourceException re) {
            // external resource unavailable, let's wait 30min
            registerNewTimer(30*60*1000);
            // last message not acknowledged, so rolled back
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to use Message Driven Beans as I would like to stay in control when to consume messages (see the delay logic in case of errors).

**The problem**:
The error is in the `@PostConstruct` annotated `init()` method: at this moment it is not allowed to use the timerService. It is allowed when I make the sessionbean `@Singleton` but then I lose the possibility to process the queue in parallel. Does anyone has an idea how to solve this ? If TimerService is not the right mechanism, what can be an alternative. Is there a PostConstruct alternative which allows access to the referenced resources and is only called once after instantiation ?

Thanks in advance for any constructive information.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution myself so I post it here so it may help others.

I added a new Singleton,Startup bean which holds a list of all beans implementing the MyJobExecutor interface thanks to CDI. In a JEE environment, CDI works well with EJBs and so it injects session beans! Warning: CDI will only inject classes which directly implement MyJobExecutor so it does not work if you have an abstract class implementing MyJobExecutor and a concrete bean extending from this abstract class. It must explicitly `implements MyJobExecutor`.
In the postconstruct of the startup class, I call every MyJobExecutor bean to register a new timer in its TimerService. This way I can create the first singleActionTimer(s) for every session bean.

```
public interface MyJobExecutor {
    // how many timers to register for this bean meaning how many parallel processes.
    public int nrOfParallellInstances();
}

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Any;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class MyJobStartup {

    @Inject
    @Any
    private Instance<MyJobExecutor> myJobs;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void startIt() {
        for (MyJobExecutor ajob : myJobs) {
            for(int i=0; i<ajob.nrOfParallellInstances(); i++)
                // register every instance with a 1 second delay between each timeout
                ajob.registerNewTimer(1000L*(i+1));
        }
    }
}
```

The inner loop will register multiple timers for the same bean based on the `ajob.nrOfParallellInstances()` value.
However, a TimerService will not trigger a timeout when the previous timeout is still running. This blocks the parallel processing as expected :(

To solve this, I adapted the timeout method to not perform the business logic itself but to launch a managed thread which performs the business logic. This way the `onTimeout` method quickly ends and the timer service will launch the next timeout resulting in multiple parallel executions (each in a managed thread):

```
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactory;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

@Resource(name = "concurrent/AsyncJobThreadFactory")
private ManagedThreadFactory threadFactory;

@Timeout
private void onTimeout(Timer timer) {
    LOG.info("Timeout triggered for " + timer.getInfo());
    Thread thread = threadFactory.newThread(new AsyncExecRunnable((String) timer.getInfo()));
    if (thread != null) {
        thread.start();
    } else {
        LOG.warn("No thread available for this job. Retry in 5 minutes.");
        registerNewTimer(1000L * 60 * 5);
    }

}
private static class AsyncExecRunnable implements Runnable {

    private String extra info;
    
    public AsyncExecRunnable(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            LOG.info("Job executor thread started for " + info);
            InitialContext ic=new InitialContext();
            // business logic. With ic you can lookup other EJBs
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Problem executing AsyncJobExecutor:", e);
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup I have:

- automatic registration of the first timer at deployment for all Session beans which implement the MyJobExecutor interface.
- posibility to register multiple timers with the same time and they will be running in parallel.
- By using a ManagedThreadFactory, also the threads have access to the JNDI context and can lookup EJBs.